# Prevent a div in absolute position from expanding the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div in absolute position that moves on scroll. I put overflow:hidden on my screen everything is ok except when I switch to responsive mode the width increases indefinitely when I scroll according to the displacement of the div. How to prevent this behavior?

For info I tried:
max-width, relative position on parent, overflow and all that doesn't work.

Par exemple HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  height: 10000px;
}
.box{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript

```
let box = document.querySelector('.box')

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
let value = window.scrollY
box.style.left = value*5 + 'px'
})
```

I wish that when scrolling the screen does not enlarge on the side

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: I put an example, Please note that overflow-x does not work responsively

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but using overflow hidden and position relative on the body did hide it:

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let value = window.scrollY
  box.style.left = value * 5 + 'px'
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried this solution it works but not in responsive mode. I want it to work on the responsive side as well.

Comment: @Helmi could you explain what you meant by "responsive side"? are you referring to chrome dev tool responsive mode (toggle device)? or is it something else? because if it's chrome dev tool toggle device, the overflow works well too, i've tried it

Comment: Yes I am talking about the chrome tool. Strange testing your solution it works fine on stack. However with Vs code I still have the same problem. Can you try this same code with Vscode and tell me if it works? Thank you

Comment: https://monweb.helmi-elmaiel-portfolio.fr/ here is the website link watch the car in responsive mode

Comment: @Helmi I think it's because your absolute car is relative to its parent (not body), a quick fix would be to add `overflow-x: hidden` to `html` like: `html {overflow-x: hidden}`

Comment: This solution has already been tried and it still doesn't work... 
What I don't understand is that your solution works on stack but not with my vscode. Have you tried on your side?